# put string in array of subject

Tags: angular

I have a message service witch include subject of messages :

```
message = new Subject<string[]>();
addMessage(message:string) {
    this.message.next(message);
}
```

and I make another service that use this (message service) to add a message :

```
logMessage(message: string):void {
    this.messageService.addMessage("HeroService: " + message)  }
}
```

then I will use message subject in component and loop throw each message :

```
constructor(private messageService: MessageService ) {
    this.messageService.messages.subscribe(h=>this.messages = h );
}
```

but above in addMessage function in message service **next** appear error (means I cannot add string type to string[]) ,so how can I add to subject and use it as array ?

Comment: `message` is a `string[]` Subject, which means that it will only emit arrays of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `addMessage()` method to this:

```
addMessage(message:string[]) {
    this.message.next(message);
}
```

Then pass the message in `logMessage()` method like this:

```
logMessage(message: string):void {
    this.messageService.addMessage(["HeroService: " + message]);
}
```

Comment: thank you , do you know how i can clear the subject ?  this.messages.next([] as any ); this statement not work

Comment: You don't need to clear the Subject. It will contain the latest value which you'll get in the subscribe.

Comment: You'll just have to clear/reinitialize `this.messages` like this: `this.messages = [];`